# How use session scope in play framework?

Tags: playframework-2.0

i want implement an authentication system for play framework.
from official documentation:

> As the Session is just a Cookie, it is also just an HTTP header, but Play provides a helper method to store a session value:

well, you are storing contents in cookies.....
Anyway, i noted that servlet 3.0 declared the new session scope that is much better than the current used in pla 2.0.
Currently, all sessions informations are stored in a cookie: this means you can store only minimal data like user.id otherwise there will be an intense http traffic.
Servlet 3.0 work like php sessions: only an id is automatically stored in client by system,
instead in the server there are all session data. Also, the cookie is regenerated each request against cookie stealt attacks.
I noted Spring already use this spec "@scope(session)" and i think this is the biggest fault in play framework..(also bugged examples in documentation are not good)
It's really not accettable current system, too slow and insicure.
**There is a way to use servlet 3.0 session scope or do you have the intention to implement it in future versions?**
regard Nicola

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you have a specific question? This site is not really a discussion forum.

Comment: hi,"Do you have the intention to implement the new?" this is the question

Comment: It sounds like you want people to discuss the topic. Have you read the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page?

Comment: you've got the wrong impression. It's not to discuss about "what system is better?", because there aren't doubts.. if i wrote how work the session system is only because i want be answered on "yes" or "no" for implementing no-arcaic system that i described for people that don't know. i really important for me because i don't spend any more time to make classes if this project don't sound fine for me

Comment: You should learn about Stateless framework, it's the keyword in this thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sessions:** Yes, that's truth, by default Play's session are stored in the coookie scope only, and I'm pretty sure that was intended somehow. Play clean implementation aims to start with minimal dependencies as it's not only targeted to build `common` web applications with forced DB usage and other `typical` things are available, but... sometimes you need to add 2cc on yourself.

**Authentication/authorization**: Fortunately you don't need to create these mechanics from the scratch, there are few public available modules, that does the job. My favorite is [Play Authenticate](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate) by Joscha Feth - complete stack, for authorization and authentication, with multilanguage support, multi provider support (Facebook, Twitter, etc), roles and permissions (with Deadbolt2) etc.

Some time ago I also published my sample, built on top of `PA`, which demonstrates better session handling, which does (almost) all that you want. It doesn't refresh `sesId` on each request, however that's just small modification. you can implement yourself. Also you're welcome to send more ideas to make the sessions even more secure, I'm opened!

Source code is published in [2.0.4_sessions](https://github.com/biesior/play-authenticate/tree/2.0.4_sessions/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage) branch in my fork. Joscha is interested about pulling it to official PA samples, anyway I'd like to deliver finished solution, so - as I wrote you can join :)